# subtracting arraylist from another arraylist

Tags: java

i have a class called ScheduleTime.

```
public class ScheduleTime {
    String date;
    Integer hours;
    Integer minutes;
}
```

now i have two ArrayList one is called timeSlots and another is called bookingArray both are of type ScheduleTime .. with some items in them.

Now i want to delete all the elements in timeSlots which are the same as elements of bookingArray

I have tried this

```
 timeSlots.removeAll(bookingArray);
```

But still timeSlots remain the same i don't know why

Comment: Things like `removeAll` will rely on the `equals` and `hashcode` support of the object to determine equality.  You could implement this interfaces or you could simply run through both arrays and manually match elements

Comment: You need to define `equals` and `hashCode` otherwise identical times will point to different references, and `equals` will fail.

Comment: There is the method [`ArrayList#removeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)). But you have to override `equals` for `ScheduleTime` so identical elements are identified.

Comment: All 3 within 3 seconds. I applaud you :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: guys can someone help me with the code ..

Comment: 3 people did. You need to implement `equals()` (and ideally, `hashCode()`) on your class.

Comment: Um, probably best if you look up a tutorial on Java equals and collections. Explaining that all is a bit much. Try e.g. [here](https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java)

Comment: @shmosel I've seen things fail **even when switching to a newer version of Java** if you fail to implement both at the same time.

Comment: Strictly speaking, to solve this problem only `equals()` needs implementing

Comment: can somebody upvote my question??  i think its a nice question

Comment: @aspertimetechnologies Generally we don't post comments with any recommendations to upvote/downvote or close, aspertime. People should make up their own minds about it.

Comment: For the `Duration` that we can still comment here: I think I can solve this problem in an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for sharing already existing link it worked!